# JavaScript: Creating mulitdimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have made an array that is used to loop through a table (initially hidden) and display certain rows depending on which section is requested:

```
var rows_per_section = [ {min: 0, max: 7}, {min: 7, max: 17}, {min: 17, max: 21}, {min: 21, max: 35}, {min: 35, max: 41}, {min: 41, max: 46}, {min: 46, max: 52},{min: 52, max: 56} ];
var rows_min = rows_per_section[section_no].min;
var rows_max = rows_per_section[section_no].max;
```

I am now trying to alter the script with an extra function that cycles through the table and creates the rows_per_section array on its own as the length of the table can be varied.  I can detect the breaks in the table by looking for a class tag but I cannot figure out how to create the array and add new values every time it hits a break:

```
function create_section_array(profile_table, no_of_sections) {
    var section_counter = 0;
    var rows_per_section = new Array();    //this is where it starts to go wrong
                                           //need to create the array and stick in the
                                           //MIN value for the first section as 0
    for (i=0;i<profile_table.length-1;i++) {
        var table_row = profile_table.item(i);
        var row_content = table_row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        if(row_content[0].className == "ProfileFormTitle") {
            if(section_counter != 0) {
                //if not the first section add a MAX value to
                //rows_per_section[section_counter + 1]
            }
            if(section_counter != no_of_sections) {
                //if not the last section add a MIN value to
                //rows_per_section[section_counter]
            }
            section_counter++;
        }
    }
    return rows_per_section;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify your function to look something like this:

```
function create_section_array (profile_table, no_of_sections) {
    var section_counter = 0,
        rows_per_section = [ { min: 0 } ],
        precedingLength = 0,
        i, row_content;

    for (i = 0; i < profile_table.length; i += 1) {
        row_content = profile_table[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

        if (row_content[0].className === 'ProfileFormTitle') {
            if (section_counter !== 0) {
                rows_per_section[section_counter] = {
                    max: row_content.length - 1
                };
            }

            if (section_counter !== no_of_sections) {
                rows_per_section[section_counter].min = precedingLength;
            }

            section_counter += 1;
            precedingLength += row_content.length;
        }
    }

    return rows_per_section;
}
```

A few notes on the above:

- `i` was not explicitly declared originally, meaning it existed globally. I've added the declaration.
- There is no block scope in JavaScript, only function scope ([vars are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)). I've moved the declaration of `row_content` to the top of the function as that is the prevalent idiomatic style.
- The operators `==` and `!=` [perform type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). It is generally safer to stick to `===` and `!==` instead.
- You can declare arrays with literal syntax, there's no need for `new Array()`. In your case, we initialise using `[ { min: 0 } ]` to set up the basic required structure, but more commonly you see people initialise with the empty array, `[]`.
- Likewise, when setting the value of new indices in the array, we can use literal object syntax for the basic required structure. In your case, this is `{ max: row_content.length - 1 }`.
- Technically, this isn't a multi-dimensional array, it is an array of objects (or dictionaries, maps, key/value stores, whatever you want to call them).
- I haven't actually run the above and only have a vague sense of the context to your problem. There may be (are probably?) issues with this code! :)